# Parallax getting strange padding on background on mobile

Tags: css, wordpress

Spent hours on this issue and can't locate it.
http://www.serwer1668391.home.pl/stolwit/#

This is the website. 
There is strange padding on background - top and right, even if it is nowhere in CSS.

[image]

Can some CSS gutu look into this and tell me what I am doing wrong?

It is 'shapely' theme for Wordpress but I did some modification on header height and then issues came up...

Comment: can you please add a screenshot? I can not see any strange padding at my end

Comment: sorry, forgot to attached before. Done. Please remove close...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your `.nav-container` has a min-height of 117px but the content inside does not occupy that much of space hence you have that empty space, its not padding. you just need to reduce the min-height or remove it completely.

[image]

Also, try to clean your cache as I don't see the same result in my browser as shown in the screenshot, that could be one problem. You can use https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-super-cache/ or any other cache management plugin.

Comment: tried it. IF you will disable it with dev-tools the issue still persists. Also it does not explain space on right

Comment: I actually did and it does work and I do not see any space on right.

Comment: found what is the issue that you have it working - try to enable any MOBILE, instead of responsive... You will immediately see the issue

Comment: try clearing your cache in wordpress, it creates a lot of problems at times and try to reproduce the problem and try to remove the min-height

Comment: removed it now. on real phone looks ok. How to clean cache in wordpress?

Comment: I use this plugin: works really well for me, apart from clearing cache it gives you a lot of other functionalities to reduce the load time: https://wordpress.org/plugins/w3-total-cache/

Comment: Thanks.  Accepted your answer. Please move info about cache to answer to make it better for people in future